# How to extract numerical data from a text file

Tags: python

I have a data in a single column in a text file like this:

2305\n1961\n2224\n1223\n. when I read this data it changes data_type to string.

```
data = open('C:\file.txt','r')
lines = data.readlines()
new_data = []
for i in range(len(lines)):
    new_data.append(lines[i].strip())
    print new_data
```

This produces ['2305','1961','2224','1223']
however I want above output without delimiters " ' "

I tried this but doesn't work

```
no_list = []
for list in new_data:
    no_list.append(int(list))
print no_list
```

and still the same result as previous. ow can I get the numerical data in int format.

Comment: Your second code block gives me `[2305, 1961, 2224, 1223]`. Are you sure that's exactly the code you're running?

Comment: Oops! I was continuously looking for solutions and in the meanwhile didn't figure out that I got the solution. My second code is working fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to convert the list from a collection of `string` to `int` types.  The first thing I would note, however, is this: don't iterate twice over the list if you don't have to.  When you're iterating, read the data in, convert it to the type, and append it:

```
for line in data.readlines():
    new_data.append(int(line.strip()))
```

This could be shortened by using a list comprehension or `map` call:

```
new_data = map(int, data.readlines())
new_data = [int(line) for line in data.readlines()]
```

If you must iterate over it twice, you can use a list comprehension or `map` to convert it:

```
no_data = [int(num) for num in new_data]
# or
no_data = map(int, new_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply take the UTF-8 string type input and use the built in int() function.
I've made the necessary change to your code below. I've also made it so that you'll only iterate over the list of lines once, and simplified the flow of the program to be more easily understood.

```
lines = open('C:\file.txt','r').readlines()
new_data = []
for line in lines:
    new_data.append(int(line.strip()))
print new_data
```

Enjoy and good luck.